# What's the relationship between AVPacket in FFMpeg and H.264 NAL Uint?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, h.264, x264

I use FFMpeg's api to encode images to H.264 stream, the code is like this [encode code](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/19044698f91fefa9cb75328c44f7a487d336b541/ffmpeg/encode.c). When I called the function `avcodec_encode_video2` I got one AVPacket's data, then I saved it to file. I use several images to get several files for test.
Based on the startcode `00 00 00 01` or `00 00 01`, I found that the 1st and 2nd files' data both contain several H.264 NAL Uints. But start from the third file, I can't found the startcode. Like followed image.
[image: Picture]

I feel confused. Base on the FFMpeg's code I think one AVPacket's data should contain at least one NAL Uint, but the result is unexpected. Is that means one NAL Uint may be divided to two AVPackets' data? What's the relationship between AVPacket and H.264 NAL Uint?

Comment: Can you show your code? I'm suspecting that your encode call did not actually return a packet (got_packet_ptr == 0) or something like that.

Comment: From [FFmpeg doxygen](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__encoding.html#gaa2dc9e9ea2567ebb2801a08153c7306b) on `avcodec_encode_video2`: *Takes input raw video data from frame and writes the next output packet, if available, to avpkt. The output packet **does not necessarily contain data for the most recent frame**, as encoders can delay and reorder input frames internally as needed.* So probably it is splited. Can you concatenate the data and feed it to decoder to see if its complaining or not?

Comment: @RonaldS.Bultje I debug my program, the `got_output` actually be true every time.

Comment: @incBrain The bit stream of the 3rd AVPacket's data have bits like this `1034 9ab2 047f 0000 a0f7 816e 047f 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 70c6 5eb2 047f 0000`. I think continuous `00 00 00` should be replace with `00 00 03 00` by encoder if the avpkt is normal. Feel like the 3rd avpkt is wrong.

Comment: @Ello can you post the code nonetheless?

Comment: @RonaldS.Bultje https://gist.github.com/esrever10/14361dd8bf578a0426e9d4bdf3f44698 Here is the code

Comment: @incBrain, even if the raw Frame was encoded in delay or split, but one AVPacket should be included one NAL unit at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some test, I found that it's just my stupid mistake.
I got the avpkt and `setRawData` to QByteArray in Qt, then save the bytearray to file. Before save, I called `av_packet_unref` to reset the avpkt. I thought that `setRawData` would copy the avpkt's data, but actually the QByteArray only contain the data pointer. So one AVPacket's data contain at least one complete NAL Uint, it's correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
00 00 00 01 41.....
........00 00 01 41
....00 00 01 41......
.......
```

After I tested, except the beginners, the following NAL all separated by
00 00 01, and NAL type is same, too.
So each AVPacket should include one NAL at least.